# How to to autodeploy war file with GlassFish -- from "Core JavaServerFaces" by David Geary, Cay S. Horstmann

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, autodeploy

*Naive question, but this is my first step in JSF, so forgive me ;-)*

I am following all the steps of the first example from "Core JavaServerFaces" by David Geary, Cay S. Horstmann (the 3rd edition).

What works in general:

- java works
- glassfish works
- I can compile the attached code
- I can create .war file

The problem begins when I copy the war file into autodeploy subdirectory of GlassFish and try to show the appropriate page in GF. In return I get 404 error and in logs I find this:

> Selecting file /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/login.war for autodeployment.
>
> Module type not recognized for module /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/login
>
> There is no installed container capable of handling this application login
>
> Autodeploy failed : /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/login.war.

glassfish 3.1.2, java 1.6.0_29, opensuse 11.4.

**The question is** how to make this code work?

### Updates

> jar tvf login.war

```
     0 Thu Apr 12 22:24:24 CEST 2012 META-INF/
    71 Thu Apr 12 22:24:24 CEST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 src/
     0 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 src/java/
     0 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 src/java/com/
     0 Thu Apr 12 22:16:32 CEST 2012 src/java/com/corejsf/
   603 Thu Apr 12 22:16:32 CEST 2012 src/java/com/corejsf/UserBean.java
     0 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 web/
     0 Thu Apr 12 21:24:56 CEST 2012 web/WEB-INF/
   877 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 web/WEB-INF/web.xml
     0 Thu Apr 12 22:21:38 CEST 2012 web/WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Thu Apr 12 22:21:38 CEST 2012 web/WEB-INF/classes/com/
     0 Thu Apr 12 22:21:38 CEST 2012 web/WEB-INF/classes/com/corejsf/
   704 Thu Apr 12 22:21:38 CEST 2012 web/WEB-INF/classes/com/corejsf/UserBean.class
     0 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 web/WEB-INF/beans.xml
   786 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 web/index.xhtml
   394 Mon Jun 27 10:13:54 CEST 2011 web/welcome.xhtml
```

Comment: Show the output of "jar tvf login.war".

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your WAR file is broken.

Package it up in the web folder instead.  WEB-INF should be in the root.