# How to make a war file auto deploy?

Tags: glassfish, war

How do you make a war file auto deploy?
The server component is glassfish and the database is created in MySQL. Do I need to create an executable file that will extract the war file? and how to do it so?

Comment: When do you need to auto deploy the war file? Because once you have deployed a web application in Glassfish, it will automatically be redeployed when the Glassfish starts again if the application was running when the Glasssfish got restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be sufficient to copy/move your WAR file to the following folder:

`$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy`

(You may change the domain name if you are using a different one.)

**See also:**

- [How to to autodeploy war file with GlassFish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147995/how-to-to-autodeploy-war-file-with-glassfish-from-core-javaserverfaces-by-d)
- [WAR doesn't get redeployed in Glassfish from autodeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467756/war-doesnt-get-redeployed-in-glassfish-from-autodeploy)
- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Quick Start Guide - Deploying and Undeploying Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html)